# Max word embedding

Tags: word-embeddings, embeddings

I'm trying to understand the concept behind Max Word / Sentence embeddings also in contrast to mean word embedding. They used it for example in this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-do-average-and-max-word-embedding-for-long-sentences-f3531e99d998). So far I didn't find good resources which explain why and when to use max word / Sentence embedding. Can you recommend me any or explain it?